# Change button active script to onLoad effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple code can display a notice box in left top corner of a webpage when click to specific button.

I need the code can be displayed the notice box at the moment of webpage is fully ready&loaded, at same place, with the same timer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ns-default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ns-style-growl.css" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="color-9">
<div class="container">
        <!-- Top Navigation -->
        <div class="main clearfix">
            <div class="column">
              <button id="notification-trigger" class="progress-button">
                  <span class="content">Show Notification</span>
                  <span class="progress"></span>
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
<!-- Related demos --></div><!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/notificationFx.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var bttn = document.getElementById( 'notification-trigger' );

            // make sure..
            bttn.disabled = false;

            bttn.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                // simulate loading (for demo purposes only)
                classie.add( bttn, 'active' );
                setTimeout( function() {

                    classie.remove( bttn, 'active' );

                    // create the notification
                    var notification = new NotificationFx({
                        message : '<p>Hello there! I\'m a classic notification but I have some elastic jelliness thanks to <a href="http://bouncejs.com/">bounce.js</a>. </p>',
                        layout : 'growl',
                        effect : 'jelly',
                        type : 'notice', // notice, warning, error or success
                        onClose : function() {
                            bttn.disabled = false;
                        }
                    });

                    // show the notification
                    notification.show();

                }, 1200 );

                // disable the button (for demo purposes only)
                this.disabled = true;
            } );
        })();
    </script>
```

Thank's a lot in advance if anyone can land me a hand to modify the code. :)

Comment: If you don't mind using jQuery, you could use `$( document ).ready()`. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: At bottom of `document.ready` (still inside it), add:  `bttn.click();`  -- it will run upon page load.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stupid, I have edited the code and work fine !

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's to help.

I have edited and find a way to do, the last  block edited here:

```
            (function() {
            var bttn = document.getElementById( 'notification-trigger' );

            // make sure..
            bttn.disabled = false;

            addEventListener('load',function() {


                    // create the notification
                    var notification = new NotificationFx({
                        message : '<p>Hello there! I\'m a classic notification but I have some elastic jelliness thanks to <a href="http://bouncejs.com/">bounce.js</a>. </p>',
                        layout : 'growl',
                        effect : 'jelly',
                        type : 'notice', // notice, warning, error or success
                        onClose : function() {
                            bttn.disabled = false;
                        }
                    });

                    // show the notification
                    notification.show();

                }, 1200 );

                // disable the button (for demo purposes only)
                this.disabled = true;

        })();
```

Thank's for the help :)
Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the click handler function separately, then you can call it after binding it, without triggering the click event, which `bttn.click()` would do.

```
// Declare handler:
var clickHandler = function (event) {
  // Your onclick function
};

bttn.addEventListener( 'click', clickHandler); // Bind handler
clickHandler(); // Fire it immediately
```